# How can I run a Python script on one HTML page, and print the results on another?

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask app where I want to click a button on the home page, which will

1. On click, run Python script and route to my results.html. (which i have done)
2. Auto-fill certain fields on that page with results from a python script. (what i need help with)

The python script (parser.py) may take a 30-40 minutes to run, as its job is to start a test that takes about that long, then process and grab/parse the results. After that, some other fields will be filled in by the user, then the form on results.html is submitted to a database.

I hope i'm closer to my answer than I think, but where/how do I introduce my python into this and pass it into the form on results.html?

parser.py

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Test data
body = pd.read_csv('path-to-test-data.csv', skiprows=11)


# Build dataframe of test info
frame = body['Frame Size']
loss = body['Loss Rate (Percent)']
speed = body['Tx Rate (L1) (Bit/s)']
grade = body['Result State']

lst = pd.concat([frame,loss,speed,grade], axis = 1)
selected_df = pd.DataFrame(data=lst)
selected_df.set_index('Frame Size')

# Select all 64b frame results
print(selected_df[np.isclose(selected_df['Frame Size'].values[:, None], [64],).any(axis=1)])

# Select all tests that fail
print(selected_df.loc[selected_df['Result State'] == 'FAIL'])
```

app.py:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, escape, request, redirect, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/results/')
def about():
    return render_template('results.html')
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>OLT TESTER</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="index">
        Press This Button to Begin Testing
    <button onclick=""></button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

results.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Results</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="results">
        <a href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Initialize Test</a>

        <form action="#.php" method="post">
            Job Order: <input type="text" name="jobOrder"><br>
            Serial Number: <input type="text" name="serialNo"><br>
            Frame Size: <input type="text" name="jobOrder"><br> <!--Fill this field with Python output -->
            Result State: <input type="text" name="serialNo"><br> <!--Fill this field with Python output -->
            <input type="submit">
        </form>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: script has to save results in file or database and other page should use JavaScript/Ajax to check periodically if results are in file or database.